# Specifying the filename of print using a variable

Tags: matlab

Does anyone know how I can use print to print out a file with a filename based on a variable?
At the moment if I do:

```
filename = 'pressure';
print -despc filename
```

it saves the file as 'filename.eps'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

like this:

```
print('-despc', filename)
```

btw, switch `-tiff` can be useful to save tiff previews of an eps file.
**to answer comment:**

```
print('-despc', '-tiff', filename)    # saves eps file with tiff preview
```

Comment: I'm using LaTeX so I'm to use EPS files for them to look nice =]